as i am running the code i am getting error that my ollama has no attribute bind_functions, the llm i am using is ollama model llama -2
# Setup your supervisor, conditional logic, and integrate the nodes into the workflow
members = ["Web_Searcher", "Web_Searcher_Quality","Blog_Searcher", "Blog_Searcher_Quality", "Content_Writer"]
system_prompt = (
    """As a supervisor, your role is to oversee a dialogue between these
    workers: {members}. and excute all the agents one by one,
    determine which worker should take the next action. Each worker is responsible for
    executing a specific task and reporting back their findings and progress. Once all tasks are complete,
    indicate with 'FINISH'."""
)

options = ["FINISH"] + members
function_def = {
    "name": "route",
    "description": "Select the next role.",
    "parameters": {
        "title": "routeSchema",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {"next": {"title": "Next", "anyOf": [{"enum": options}] }},
        "required": ["next"],
    },
}

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", system_prompt),
    MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="messages"),
    ("system", "Given the conversation above, who should act next? Or should we FINISH? Select one of: {options}"),
]).partial(options=str(options), members=", ".join(members))

manager_chain = (prompt | llm.bind_functions(functions=[function_def], function_call="route") | JsonOutputFunctionsParser())

i am expecting it to run, i dot know why i am getting stuck, this is the output i am getting.
flow
manager_chain = (prompt | llm.bind_functions(functions=[function_def], function_call="route") | JsonOutputFunctionsParser())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Ollama' object has no attribute 'bind_functions'

As the error indicates, the Ollama class does not have a bind_functions() method. In contrast, the ChatOpenAI class does have a bind_functions() method.
Ollama doesn't natively support function calling, but an experimental OllamaFunctions wrapper class was created that gives it the same API as OpenAI Functions.
Example:
from langchain_experimental.llms.ollama_functions import OllamaFunctions

model = OllamaFunctions(model="llama2")

model = model.bind(
    functions=[
        {
            "name": "route",
            "description": "Select the next role.",
            "parameters": {
                "title": "routeSchema",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {"next": {"title": "Next", "anyOf": [{"enum": options}] }},
                "required": ["next"],
            },
        }
    ],
    function_call={"name": "route"},
)

This implementation may work for your function calling use case. But, as the documentation states, "more powerful and capable models will perform better with complex schema and/or multiple functions."
References:

OllamaFunctions (LangChain)
Ollama (GitHub)


any ideas how to add mulitple tools? do i need to call .bind multiple times or its there a simpler syntax
